# Injecting newline after specific word in text with tritium

Tags: html, tritium

I have a span node that needs a newline inserted after a certain word. Whenever I use tritium to get into the inner() or text() scope I can't figure out how to inject a break in a way that the browser will interpret as a new node and not text. I don't want to grab the first half as a var and put them in a new node, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work: You might also want to wrap the

```
$("xpath") {
  inner() {
     replace(/(regex)/, '<br /> $1') 
     # This will work also:
     # replace(/(regex)/, '<span class="mw-block">$1</span>'
  } 
}
```